# segue from UITableViewCell to DetailViewController not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've got this problem where when running my app on the iOS simulator, a segue I have from a custom table view cell to a detail view controller doesn't work. I can click on the cell but then the app freezes and I can no longer do anything without having to stop running the app and restart it. I have such segues in a few places in my app, and only one of them works fine, the others don't. I've made sure that the segue identifier is okay, still nothing works. Any ideas on why this is happening?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

        let detailViewController: DetailTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailTableViewController

        let objectAtIndex: Tasks = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Tasks

        detailViewController.receivingObject = objectAtIndex

    }

}
```

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: @SahilKapoor absolutely, give me a moment

Comment: I've tried many things and I don't think it has anything to do with my code since I'm using the same code in another table view controller that shows its own detail view controller. Plus I've tried to print a message to the console if the prepareForSegue method gets called and it does, but only once. It doesn't show my detail view controller and the app freezes at that moment.

Comment: Do you have navigation controller in the middle?

Comment: and what is receivingObject? hopefully not an outlet

Comment: @Lukas I have a navigation controller that manages the table view controller I am trying to send data from to the detail TVC, but no navigation controller in the middle.

Comment: @Lukas receivingObject is the optional variable of type Tasks (core data class) that should be receiving the data i am trying to pass to the detail TVC.

Comment: I added an answer to help figure out where exactly the problem might be. can you try it and see which error message you get?

Answer (score 1):

Add this extension to by pass nav controllers while segueing

```
extension UIViewController{
    var visibleVC: UIViewController {
        if self is UINavigationController{
            if let cvc = (self as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController { return cvc }
        }
        return self 
    }
}
```

and try this prepare segue func

```
if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell{
             let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
             if let let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController. visibleVC as! DetailTableViewController{
                  if let objectAtIndex = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Tasks{
                      detailViewController.receivingObject = objectAtIndex
                  } else { print("unlikely") }
             } else { print("wiring problem in storyboard") }
        } else { print("segue is not initiated from a cell") }
 }
```

This will at list make it easier to figure out where the problem is but I think its just the nav vc getting in the way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!. I've tried your solution yet nothing gets printed to the console meaning that all the right code was run. The same problem persists, it still freezes... as if the proper code in the prepareForSegue method was run and it was going to show the detail TVC but never gets there. I created a new TVC and added a segue from the cell to it and everything there works properly. So I'm thinking the problem might be the detail view controller itself for some reason. Weird because it was working juste 2 days ago.

Comment: do you have the project in github?

Comment: I decided to create a new view controller with a new class and copied and pasted all the code from the old detail TVC to the new one. For some reason it's working just fine. I honestly have no idea what the problem was. Thanks so much for your time :)